# angular component routing to home page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

Hi Im having some issues routing back to some pages in Ionic. I'm trying to create a header component which will have a side menu that will link to different pages. But I also want to be able to turn off the header on certain pages. I'm able to see the header component on my media page, but the routerLink doesn't work. Here is my code;

header-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HeaderComponent
  },
  {
      path: 'home',
      loadChildren: '../../../pages/landing/home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HeaderRoutingModule {}
```

header.component.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="toolbar">
    <ion-buttons slot="secondary">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="person-circle"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button color="danger">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" ios="ellipsis-horizontal" md="ellipsis-vertical"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button routerLink="/home">Home</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

component.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
      HeaderComponent
  ],

  exports: [
      HeaderComponent
  ]
})
export class PageComponentsModule { }
```

media.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MediaPageRoutingModule } from './media-routing.module';

import { MediaPage } from './media.page';
import { PageComponentsModule } from '../components/page-component.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    PageComponentsModule,
    MediaPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [MediaPage]
})
export class MediaPageModule {}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used i work around for this, had a simular case and this is how i fixed it.
This might not be the best practice so please if anybody with more experience in rooting have something more sold i would also like to learn.

1. i will remove routerLink and add (click) event  `<ion-button (click)="onHomeRoute()">Home</ion-button>`
2. then inside the controller i will:

Imports

```
 "import { Router } from '@angular/router';"
```

Constructor

```
(private router: Router)
```

And then i will add `this.router.navigate(['/home']);` inside my click event like so,

```
onHomeRoute(){
this.router.navigate(['/home'])
}
```

i hope this will assist you as well and like i said if anybody have better solutions please comment i would also like to know. 
cheers.

Comment: thanks @MrBowie20 for taking the time to answer my question. the above answer has worked for me. Not sure why the routerLink link doesn't work. Maybe like you say if someone else has a good explanation on this that would be great!